# Unrecognized statement type. (near REVOKE) in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

[image: E]

Hello, I can easily create and grant privileges to users but when I try to revoke, I cannot do it. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: do you have the rights to perform this action with the user running this query?

Comment: From manual `To use that REVOKE syntax, you must have the GRANT OPTION privilege, and you must have the privileges that you are revoking.`

Comment: How, I tried writing GRANT OPTION, but still same error

Comment: Yes, I have all the priviliges

Comment: Show `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;` output. PS. This may be phpmyadmin issue easily...

Comment: Updated in the post, I logged in with root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these all working for me even with Err/Warning, hence can be ignored...

(works within phpMyAdmin or login to MySQL server)

```
GRANT INSERT ON *.* TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost'; 
...
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
...
REVOKE INSERT ON  *.* FROM 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
```

[image]

Comment: I spent like hours to check it and didn't run it :D thanks for the answer. It is working.